# How to remove characters starting from X until the end

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for a function in `VB.NET` that will allow me to remove X until the end of the string

Supposed **`X = ":"`**, this means that starting from **`:`** to the `end of the string` should be removed.

**Example 1:**

String: `Cary:Bondoc`

Result: `Cary`

**Example 2:**

String: `192.168.111.111:23512`

Result: `192.168.111.111`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code:

```
Dim str = "192.168.1.1:8080"
Dim x = ":"
Dim index = str.IndexOf(x)
If (index >= 0) Then
    str = str.Substring(0, index)
End If
MessageBox.Show(str)
```

And the result will be 192.168.1.1

The key point is in using IndexOf and Substring methods.

[**String.IndexOf Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of a specified
>   Unicode character or string within this instance. The method returns
>   -1 if the character or string is not found in this instance.

[**String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position and has a specified length.

Comment: Yes, this is working. Thanks! combining IndexOf and Substring, nice.

Comment: Good answer, just one very minor complaint: the test `index < str.Length` is not necessary: `IndexOf` won't ever find a character after the end of the string. Also, in the same line of code, `AndAlso` (short-circuiting) should be chosen over `And`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei please note that if I test `192.168.111.111:60414` it outputs `60414` not the IP.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I did't know you had such a VB know-how

Answer (score 3):

Why not use simple `Split`.

```
Dim msg = "192.168.111.111:23512".Split(":")
MsgBox(msg(0))

msg = "Cary:Bondoc".Split(":")
MsgBox(msg(0))
```

`Split` by `:` delimiter and always take first one from array. By me, easiest way shortest way.

Or, there another way :

```
Dim msg As String = "Cary:Bondoc"
StrRem(msg, ":")
MsgBox(msg)

Private Sub StrRem(ByRef msg As String, ByVal del As String)
    Dim res = msg.Split(del)
    msg = res(0)
End Sub
```

Using `ByRef` in subroutine, `msg` variable will be updated with result. So, by this way You don't need function.

Comment: Yes, I know... don't ask me why I put it :) ... fast typing :) ... update

Comment: And just a personal opinion to share, I don't prefer creating new functions to cover such requirement.

Comment: Of course... this is just example, to show how `function` can be replaced with `sub` in some cases. Easiest way it's first example from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
Dim msg As String
Dim X As String = ":"
msg = "192.168.111.111:23512"
MsgBox(CutString(msg, X))
```

And the function looks like this:

```
Private Function CutString(ByVal str As String, ByVal X As Char) As String
    Dim l, p As Integer
    l = str.Length
    p = str.IndexOf(X)
    If p = -1 Then p = l
    CutString = str.Remove(p, l - p)
End Function
```